# AS3 with image saving with PHP on server

Tags: actionscript

I am passing 3 params from AS3/flash to PHP server, first 2 params are strings and 3rd is encoded JPG image. Before sending, image is saved local from byteArray so I can check was encoding OK and then sending with 2 other params with PHP POST.

Problem is: first 2 params are OK, but the third one (jpg encoded image) is not, I get something like `Ã¿ÃÃ¿Ã`  on the server side, or so, a few characters and that's it. On local drive at same time (actually before sending to server) JPG is visible can open and see everything, but on server like I said I see new .jpg file but just few few chars inside.

On server side I am writing data with :

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Flash gives message

> Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must
>   be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.

So I see upload of all 3 params is executed and 2 are OK and 3rd (image) is not.

So what am I doing wrong? Is the problem that I am passing 2 string vars and 1 image at same time? Or something with headers?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for uploading the image? How are you adding the parameters to the request? From the Adobe ActionScript3 docs: "To send POST or GET parameters to the server, set the value of URLRequest.data to your parameters, and set URLRequest.method to either URLRequestMethod.POST or URLRequestMethod.GET."
[link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html)

Comment: After making image here is a code:

Comment: Based on your description it's not exactly clear if you want to do a file upload where the user can select a file, or if you want to do an upload of an image without any user interaction. The answer I provided is the form/file selection upload scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the upload() method of the FileReference object when uploading files. Here's a simple ActionScript 3 application which shows you how to upload a file with Flash while passing additional parameters with the request (they'll be passed as GET/querystring params:

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.DataEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class FileUploader extends Sprite
    {

        private var request:URLRequest;
        private var file:FileReference;

        public function FileUploader() {
            var theText:TextField = new TextField();
            theText.text = "Click here to select file!";
            theText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            this.addChild(theText);
            theText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectFile);
            request = new URLRequest();
            request.url = "http://192.168.178.75/upload/upload.php";
        }

        private function selectFile(evt:Event):void {
            file = new FileReference();
            configureListeners(file);
            file.browse(getTypes());
        }

        public function uploadImage(file:FileReference):void {
            var myData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            myData.user = "valueOfUserParam";
            myData.filename = file.name;
            request.data = myData;
            // "filedata": in PHP, the file can be accessed using $_FILE['filedata']
            file.upload(request, "filedata");
        }

        private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,uploadCompleteDataHandler);
        }

        private function getTypes():Array {
            var allTypes:Array = new Array(getImageTypeFilter(), getTextTypeFilter());
            return allTypes;
        }

        private function getImageTypeFilter():FileFilter {
            return new FileFilter("Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png");
        }

        private function getTextTypeFilter():FileFilter {
            return new FileFilter("Text Files (*.txt, *.rtf)", "*.txt;*.rtf");
        }

        private function cancelHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("cancelHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("completeHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function uploadCompleteDataHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("uploadCompleteData: " + event);
        }

        private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
            trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("openHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
            trace("progressHandler name=" + file.name + " bytesLoaded=" + event.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + event.bytesTotal);
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
            var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
            trace("selectHandler: name=" + file.name + " URL=" + request.url);
            this.uploadImage(file);
        }

    }
}
```

And the server-side PHP code I've used for testing:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/";

header("content-type: text/xml");
?><result>
<?php
if (empty($_FILES)) { ?>
  <message>No file has been uploaded!</message>
<?php
} else {
  $filename = $_FILES['filedata']['name'];
  // Mark the file with a timestamp
  $filename = str_replace(".jpg", time().".jpg", $filename);
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;
  $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

  if ($success)  {
?>
  <message>File is valid, and was successfully uploaded</message>
  <debug>
    <files><![CDATA[<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>]]></files>
    <post><![CDATA[<?php print_r($_POST); ?>]]></post>
    <get><![CDATA[<?php print_r($_GET); ?>]]></get>
  </debug>
<?php
    } else {
?>
  <message>File upload failed miserably</message>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</result>
```

Put the PHP file into the root folder of your webserver, and images should be uploaded into a subfolder img - which you have to create.

The trace output in debug mode should look like this:

```
selectHandler: name=Penny_test.jpg URL=http://localhost/upload/upload.php
openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
progressHandler name=Penny_test.jpg bytesLoaded=11201 bytesTotal=11201
completeHandler: [Event type="complete" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
uploadCompleteData: [DataEvent type="uploadCompleteData" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 data="<result>
  <message>File is valid, and was successfully uploaded</message>
  <debug>
    <files><![CDATA[Array
(
    [filedata] => Array
        (
            [name] => Penny_test.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpaUurZr
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 11201
        )

)
]]></files>
    <post><![CDATA[Array
(
    [Filename] => Penny_test.jpg
    [Upload] => Submit Query
)
]]></post>
    <get><![CDATA[Array
(
    [filename] => Penny_test.jpg
    [user] => valueOfUserParam
)
]]></get>
  </debug>
</result>"]
```